# Paperclip S3 symbolize_keys error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am currently implementing S3 integration into my Rais application which uses Paperclip. Currently, my model looks as such:

```
:has_attached_file :picture, :styles => {:medium => "300x300"},

:storage => :s3,

:s3_credentials => S3_CREDENTIALS,

:path => "/:style/:id/:filename"
```

S3_CREDENTIALS is defined in a file under config/initalizers named s3.rb:

```
if Rails.env == "production"
#set credentials from ENV hash
S3_CREDENTIALS = {:access_key_id => ENV['S3_KEY'],
                :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET'],
                :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET']}
else
S3_CREDENTIALS = Rails.root.join("config/s3.yml")
end
```

The production hases are stored on heroku while the development hash is stored in the s3.yml file. When I call this line in my view,

```
<%= image_tag (item.picture.url(:medium), :class => "iteminfo" %>
```

I get a undefined method symbolize_keys error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the parentheses in your image_tag

```
<%= image_tag (item.picture.url(:medium), :class => "iteminfo") %>
```

*Notice the last parentheses*

Comment: Thanks for that! Much appreciated. It's now throwing out a 
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...ag (item.picture.url(:medium) , :class => "iteminfo") );@out...
which seems rather odd considering the comma is already there. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is saying the comma is unexpected, and that it is expecting a parentheses. What exactly does that line that is erroring look like now?

Comment: Just like yours. I'm actually probably going to drop the class argument seeing as I don't use it in my CSS.

Comment: There should be no space between `image_tag` and parentheses.